# Caret in SQL Regular Expressions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm studying regular expressions and cannot figure out what this caret does exactly. I thought that this caret symbol means 'not equal', but in this query below, I am confused:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('San Antonio', '(^[[:alpha:]]+)', 'CITY') TEST
FROM DUAL;
```

RESULT:

> CITY Antonio

'San' should comply with [:alpha:] so I don't understand what the caret function does here.

Answer (score 5):

Carrat (^) also stands for the beginning of the line (and Dollar ($) for its end).

```
^Hello$  = the word Hello and nothing more
^Hello.* = something that starts with Hello
```

The negation functionality is within square brackets:

```
[^0-9]    = anything that is not a digit  
[^a-zA-Z] = anything that is not an english letter
```

Answer (score 0):

**Caret** ^ (please note the correct spelling) means "at the beginning of the string", but only when it is the very first character in the matching pattern.

`'San'` does NOT comply with `[:alpha:]`, because `[:alpha:]` is a SINGLE alphabetic character. `[ ... ]` means "matching set" (match exactly ONE SINGLE character of those listed within square brackets). `[[:alpha:]]` means any single alphabetic character. The `+` means "one or more" of what precedes it, so `'San'` matches `[[:alpha:]]+` at the beginning of the string. `'Antonio'` also matches, but it is not at the beginning of the string, so it is not replaced. If you didn't have the caret, both words would be replaced with `CITY` (try it and you will see.)